# Why is $BPP^{NP}$ in the polynomial hierarchy?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Why is $BPP^{NP}$ in the polynomial hierarchy?
I know that $BPP$ is contained in $NP^{NP}$, so $BPP$ is inside $PH$. Should I just simply reuse the proof of $BPP\subset NP^{NP}$, feed in each machine an oracle solving 3SAT problem, and show that $BPP^{NP}\subset NP^{NP^{NP}}$? Is it because normally, the proof in complexity theory can be easily relativized by an oracle?

Comment: Have you tried following your suggested proof technique?

Comment: You already got advice on how to prove it: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/43843/5038.  domotorp suggested exactly this.  Now it sounds to me like you're coming here to ask "should I do what I was advised to do?".  Well, I would think a reasonable answer is "yes, give it a try and see what happens, probably they had a reason to suggest that; and then if you run into some specific step where you get stuck, ask about that step".  Have I misunderstood the situation?